# Problem in installing mysql on my Fedora11 machine

Tags: mysql, fedora, fedora11

i got problem when i install mysql on my fedora11 machine 
This was the error face

```
gem install mysql
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
can't find header files for ruby.


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

Have you any idea.

Answer (score 0):

why you use fedora 11 now they are any more updates install fedora 13

yum install mysql

if you want build manualy mysql you need install ruby-devel

yum install ruby-devel